# How to change Pokémon Trainer Club email?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

How can I change the email address to which the activation email is sent? When I send the email, it can't be received because I use the one of my school and it can only send and receive emails from the other school emails.

Comment: If an answer has solved or at least clarified your issue can you please consider marking it as accepted by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be: don't use an email with recieve restrictions!

If your school email cannot recieve outside email, you're just going to have to set up your account using another email account.

If you're looking to "activate" that means you've not got an account yet, so there's nothing to actually change - just start afresh.

Comment: And, how, exactly, is he supposed to do that?

Comment: he way he's asking sounds like he's only at the activation stage, so doesn't actually have an account. so when he applies, he simply uses a different address

Comment: edited to include that info